# SQL Server - OPENXML how to get attribute value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have the following XML:

```
<Field FieldRowId="1000">
    <Items>
        <Item Name="CODE"/>
        <Item Name="DATE"/>
    </Items>
</Field>
```

I need to get the FieldRowId using OPENXML. The SQL i have so far:

```
INSERT INTO @tmpField
      ([name], [fieldRowId])
SELECT [Name], --Need to get row id of the parent node
 FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/Field/Items/Item', 1)
```

Comment: As noted in the tags, you are using SQL Server 2005 which natively supports XML data type. Why don't you use that instead?

Comment: Due to the limitation in the data layer in our application, the SP cannot use a xml data type input param. Is there a way I can keep the VARCHAR(MAX) input param and convert that into XML datatype somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: I added a root node to the xml.  and demonstrated grabbing the ID.  I'm assuming you have more than one field element in the xml.  This is assuming you have the starting XML; are you given an Item and have to traverse upwards?

```
DECLARE @T varchar(max) 
SET @T = 
'<root>
    <Field FieldRowId="1000">
        <Items>
            <Item Name="CODE"/>
            <Item Name="DATE"/>
        </Items>
    </Field>
    <Field FieldRowId="2000">
        <Items>
            <Item Name="CODE"/>
            <Item Name="DATE"/>
        </Items>
    </Field>
</root>'

DECLARE @X xml

SET @X = CAST(@T as xml)
SELECT Y.ID.value('../../@FieldRowId', 'int') as FieldID, 
       Y.ID.value('@Name', 'varchar(max)') as "Name"
FROM @X.nodes('/root/Field/Items/Item') as Y(ID)
```

Comment: So, If once I have the xml variable, how do I do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: You can either use it directly as Lurker showed or you can use OPENXML as I talk about http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/0,289483,sid87_gci1347994,00.html.

Answer (score 0):

Using nodes is the way to go. `OPENXML` takes 1/8 of the SQL server memory every time it is used. Although `OPENXML` and nodes will generally have the same query performance.