# SQL Server 2014: Extracting data from XML using OpenXML and BulkColumn

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to extract data from a big xml file using **OpenXML** and **BulkColumn** and then save it into a new table called badges.
I am also executing a **select** statement to show the content of the table.
The file is stored locally. The file uses the attribute-centric mapping and has tens of thousands of rows. 
The code I am using is:

```
    CREATE TABLE dbo.badges (
        Id              int,
        Name            NVARCHAR(1000),
        Date            date,
        Class           smallint,
        TagBased        nvarchar(10),

    );

    DECLARE @XMLDoc XML;    
    DECLARE @XMLDocID INT;  
    SELECT @XMLDoc = BulkColumn 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Zuhair\Desktop\Badges.xml', SINGLE_BLOB);    

    EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLDocID OUTPUT, @XMLDoc;

    SELECT  Id, Name, Date, Class, TagBased
    FROM    OPENXML(@XMLDocID, '/badges/row')
    WITH    (Id int 'Id',
                Name NVARCHAR(1000) 'Name',
                Date date 'Date',
                Class smallint 'Class',
                TagBased nvarchar(10) 'TagBased');

    INSERT INTO dbo.badges (Id, Name, Date, Class, TagBased)

    SELECT  *

    FROM    OPENXML(@XMLDocID, '/badges/row')
    WITH    (Id int 'Id',
                Name NVARCHAR(1000) 'Name',
                Date date 'Date',
                Class smallint 'Class',
                TagBased nvarchar(10) 'TagBased');

    exec sp_xml_removedocument @XMLDocID;
```

However, when I execute the above code I get the following result:

[image: query result]

Here is a sample of the XML data that I am using:

```
<badges>
  <row Id="1" UserId="2" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:03.937" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:03.997" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="3" UserId="4" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:04.107" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="4" UserId="22" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:35:05.283" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="5" UserId="33" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:35:05.330" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="6" UserId="27" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:40:05.490" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  ...
</badges>
```

Why am I getting this result rather than a table that has the desired data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - OPENXML how to get attribute value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668087/sql-server-openxml-how-to-get-attribute-value)

Comment: The current case is different from other cases in that i am using the BulkColumn (Single_Blob type) besides using OpenXML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of `FROM OPENXML` with the related procedures to prepare and remove a document are out-dated and should not be used any more.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML =
'<badges>
  <row Id="1" UserId="2" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:03.937" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:03.997" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="3" UserId="4" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:04.107" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="4" UserId="22" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:35:05.283" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="5" UserId="33" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:35:05.330" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="6" UserId="27" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:40:05.490" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
</badges>';    

SELECT r.value('@Id','int') AS Id
      ,r.value('@UserId','int') AS UserId
      ,r.value('@Name','varchar(max)') AS Name
      ,r.value('@Date','datetime') AS [Date]
      ,r.value('@Class','int') AS Class
      ,r.value('@TagBased','bit') AS TagBased
FROM @xml.nodes('/badges/row') AS A(r)
```

### UPDATE The full (minimal) code

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc XML;        
SELECT @XMLDoc = BulkColumn 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Users\Zuhair\Desktop\Badges.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;    

SELECT r.value('@Id','int') AS Id
      ,r.value('@UserId','int') AS UserId
      ,r.value('@Name','varchar(max)') AS Name
      ,r.value('@Date','datetime') AS [Date]
      ,r.value('@Class','int') AS Class
      ,r.value('@TagBased','bit') AS TagBased
FROM @XMLDoc.nodes('/badges/row') AS A(r)
```

Comment: The source file has thousands of rows. how to connect it to the select statement?

Comment: @Taie, you can use exactly the same code as your are using to retrieve your value at the moment. Change the `FROM @xml.nodes` to `FROM @XMLDoc.nodes` in order to use the existing variable. If you do not get a result, try `SELECT @XMLDoc` to check, whether you are reading your XML successfully.

Comment: @Taie, btw: I think your existing code is missing the `@` signs to mark your targets as attributes. Without the `@` your code will try to find elements...

Comment: I am still confused and still getting errors. Can you please tell me what the final code would be?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, I like Shnugo's answer and I believe that is the path you should follow.
For your specific question, the reason you got all the NULL is because you are extracting data from the ATTRIBUTE and you forgot all the @.
Try the code below:

```
DECLARE @XMLDoc XML =
'<badges>
  <row Id="1" UserId="2" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:03.937" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="2" UserId="3" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:03.997" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="3" UserId="4" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T18:25:04.107" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="4" UserId="22" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:35:05.283" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="5" UserId="33" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:35:05.330" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
  <row Id="6" UserId="27" Name="Autobiographer" Date="2010-08-11T19:40:05.490" Class="3" TagBased="False" />
</badges>';    

DECLARE @XMLDocID INT;  
EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLDocID OUTPUT, @XMLDoc;

SELECT  Id, Name, Date, Class, TagBased
FROM    OPENXML(@XMLDocID, '/badges/row')
WITH    (Id int '@Id',
            Name NVARCHAR(1000) '@Name',
            Date date '@Date',
            Class smallint '@Class',
            TagBased nvarchar(10) '@TagBased');

exec sp_xml_removedocument @XMLDocID;
```